# Add Java-Library to Android-Project

Tags: java, android, json, error-handling

I imported this morning following JAVA-Libary to my Android-Project: [JSON-Libary](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) I imported it over Project->Properties ->Add external Jar files.
After that I wrote my code with which I use this Libary, but I get this Error ouf of LogCat:

---

```
11-24 13:20:04.371: W/dalvikvm(29450): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnet/sf/json/JSONException; (420)
11-24 13:20:04.371: W/dalvikvm(29450): Link of class 'Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;' failed
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 206 (Lnet/sf/json/JSONException;)
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2e
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002e
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): VFY:  rejected Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;.toJSON (Ljava/lang/Object;Lnet/sf/json/JsonConfig;)Lnet/sf/json/JSON;
11-24 13:20:04.381: W/dalvikvm(29450): Verifier rejected class Lnet/sf/json/JSONSerializer;
```

---

It seems so that I imported this Libary the false Way, how can I use this Libary in my Android-Project, how do I need to import it that I can use it?

Thx for your help in Advance

safari

PS: I know there is a JSON-Libary in it, but I like to use this one, how can I realize 
that? To import the Libaries I tried this: [How to Import Java-Libaries](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0), but dosn't work :(
What also looks a bit strange, the libaries don't show up in "External Libaries" it looks like this:

[image: Show up false?]

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply use the `org.json` lib provided by Android?

Comment: because of the JSON Serializer: http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/flexjson/JSONSerializer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your problem is, that the `JSONException` extends the `NestableRuntimeException` from the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) project. So you need to include that jar as well.

Comment: I also imported this one 2 now, didnt work also same error as before :( i used this version: Commons Lang 3.1 (Java 5.0+)

Comment: Thats the wrong version of commons lang. The JSON lib asks for `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException`, while the package for commons lang 3 is `org.apache.commons.lang3`, because it's a major overhaul. Use a Commons Lang 2 jar and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse make sure your library gets exported to your apk at build time. Check the Java Build Path in the project properties. In the Order and Export tab check your library to be included in your apk.